# Django nested viewsets on router

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In my `urls.py` file in some app i have the following code:

```py
from rest_framework import routers

from .viewsets import (JournalViewSet, StatisticViewSet, FuelLogViewSet,
                       MoveLogViewSet, RestLogViewSet, WinLogViewSet,
                       GreatfulLogViewSet)


router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'journal', JournalViewSet)
router.register(r'journal/statistic', StatisticViewSet)
router.register(r'journal/fuel', FuelLogViewSet)
router.register(r'journal/move', MoveLogViewSet)
router.register(r'journal/rest', RestLogViewSet)
router.register(r'journal/win', WinLogViewSet)
router.register(r'journal/greatful', GreatfulLogViewSet)

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

All vievsets above are not something specific, and use only serializer_class and queryset.
Swagger generate correct scheme, but DRF says, that i have no POST method allowed (in viesets i actually have) and when i try to open url like `127.0.0.1:8000/journal/win`, drf return scheme for journal. When registers were not nested like `router.register(r'move', MoveLogViewSet)`, I get all correct. I understand, that DRF maybe don't provide nested routs like I have. What should I do?

Comment: upd: all viesets have its own serializers, and serializers have its own models. I have following models: `Journal, Statistic, FuelLog, MoveLog, RestLog, WinLog` and `GreatfulLog`, so i can't just user actions for JournalViewSet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly recommend you to read on the ***[DefaultRouter](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers#defaultrouter)*** from ***[DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org)***.

It is because the second path is a `lookup` fields in `DefaultRouter`.

`journal/fuel/` => `{prefix}/{lookup}/[.format]`

For your question:

```
from rest_framework import routers

from .viewsets import (JournalViewSet, StatisticViewSet, FuelLogViewSet,
                       MoveLogViewSet, RestLogViewSet, WinLogViewSet,
                       GreatfulLogViewSet)


router = routers.DefaultRouter()
# assessment_router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'index', JournalViewSet) # Index 
router.register(r'statistic', StatisticViewSet)
router.register(r'fuel', FuelLogViewSet)
router.register(r'move', MoveLogViewSet)
router.register(r'rest', RestLogViewSet)
router.register(r'win', WinLogViewSet)
router.register(r'greatful', GreatfulLogViewSet)

# assessment_router.register(r'dashboard', SnippetViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('journal/', include(router.urls)),
    # path('assessment/', include(assessment_router.urls)),
    # path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ]
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew about router's loopups, but kept hoping, that DRF have functionality to provide routes like I wanted. Unfortunately, it is very important for my project to have API routing with no index prefix (`journal/` instead of `journal/index`), so I just rewrite urlpatterns for class based views use. Anyway, thank you for answer!